# JS Events: Target comparison on native events

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

When an event is triggered, I have event handlers added to a div element as well as the body. I want to deduce if my target is the `<body>`.

After reading the docs, I found that I can either do `event.target === document.body` or compare the tagName by doing `event.target.tagName === 'BODY'`. Which one should/should not be used and why ?

Answer (score 0):

On your example i recommand you to use "event.target.tagName === 'BODY'" because you have warranty to have only one body tag on your application.

And compare two string together is more faster than compare two object together.

On any other case you should :

- Compare two identifier where you are sure is uniq (like id attribute ?)
- Compare with event.target === document.querySelector('mySuperSelector')